# Android:Do anybody has good method on webview screen fit?

Tags: android, html, webview, resolution

Now,I used a mode of android webview screen fit mothed:
1.set the html file's meta like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

no scale and fit the width to device-width not the target width
2. In the android activity I just set the WebView's WebSetting like this

```
               webView.setInitialScale(100);


                webView.setScrollBarStyle(1);

        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setFocusable(true);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();


                webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);


                webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);


                webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
            webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(false);
            webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);

            webSettings.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
```

no enable zoom for webview because I used the jquerymoblie framework to some place;
I found that any content like the list,form... just in the jquerymoblie's may show normal

But if you want to set some irregular picture for the background and with some text or others,
you are difficult to fit it in right place at different resolution.

And this make some different position at different resolution

I tried to fit it in all use percent width height in css,however it worked seems just not too bad.
And then I tried to use one resolution fit one css,It make lots work to me.
Because there is so many resolution in android device.And also different at diffrent version Android OS.

Do anybody have an good method to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: I found that many moto devices is not correct recognized for html files in real resolution.like xt883 is 360x640.But htc or sumsang is correct be recognized.

Comment: What I just do now is fit one resolution to one css,

Comment: It takes lots of work...

Answer (score 0):

try this. use HTML in your webView

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,
                "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style = \"text-align:center\"><img src= "
                        + \"http://www.koenvangorp.be/photos/2005_09_16-moon_2000.jpg\"
                        + " alt=\"pageNo\" width=\"100%\"></body></html>",
                "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

also refer the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) here

Comment: thanks!
but there is no use for my doing,to fix diffrent screen on android device,because if you don't use meta to set the scale and other, you can't known what the picture size will to be show,and you will never know the real width of 100% is the real picture pix,then the picture will show not right and be out of shape

Comment: Thanks,this maybe not have an best way to suit screen only with css